# Xamarin function error

Tags: android, xamarin, compiler-errors, android-emulator, emulation

I got this error when I start the emulator:

> An unhandled exception occured

I have tried to call the function `ciao` in every way, using delegate. Can someone explain why this is wrong?

```
using System;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;

namespace Prova
{

    [Activity(Label = "Prova", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]

    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {

        Button saved;
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            saved = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.Saved);
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
            saved.Click += (object sender, EventArgs e) => {
                ciao(sender, e);
            };
        }

        private void ciao (object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the rest of the exception say? Or what does the StackTrace look like? Trying clicking 'Continue' instead of 'Break' when the exception is thrown and then look in the 'Application Output' or 'Output' window for a StackTrace.

Comment: i have tried continue and also break but the emulator has a black screen

Comment: sorry, i dont say thath im using visual studio and xamarin add-on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to say for sure what the issue is since you didn't include the full exception and stacktrace, but one thing I can see here that would cause the code to fail is that you're trying to pull the button out of the UI before you actually set the view. `FindViewById()` returns null if the view can't be found, so you're likely hitting a `NullReferenceException` when trying to attach the click handler.

You should update your `OnCreate` method to look something like this:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate(bundle);

    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

    saved = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.Saved);
    saved.Click += ciao;
}
```